# How to debug "database does not exist" error in test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I recently set up a Rails dev environment on a new machine. I'm now trying to run an app's test suite, but keep getting database errors.

```
Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
PG::ConnectionBad:
FATAL:  database "test-db" does not exist
```

My database.yml file is set up correctly. I've run `psql -l` and test-db does in fact exist, and this is confirmed by running `rake db:create` where I get an 'already exists' message.

I've run `rake db:migrate` and `rake:test:prepare`, but the error still remains.

My test set up is as follows

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end
```

I'm having no trouble with the development database.

Why am I getting a db does not exist error, and what can I do to debug this?

Comment: try to enter to console using test ENV `RAILS_ENV=test rails c`. can you do it? Can you create records there? One more detail: have you restart guard/spork after test db was created?

Comment: thanks gotva. I can access the console using `RAILS_ENV=test rails c`, however I am unable to create records in the test database. Using the development console/ database, I can create records with no problem. Incidentally, I have just dropped my local databases and re-creates and re-migrated them. I'm at a loss as to why the two dbs (dev and test) are behaving differently. Appreciate any more ideas, and happy to provide more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally managed to get the test database working. Leaving the following here in case anyone else runs into this issue.

The issue was either an incorrect username in database.yml (While I did change these values, I don't think this was the cause as both development and test were using the same username previously).

Or a small spelling mistake in a config var set up elsewhere `ENV["DATABASE_URL"] = "postgres://localhost/test_db"`. This should have been `test-db`.

Comment: There is a bug that left the old schema.rb file on my system.  Renaming that allowed me to create and migrate the db.

Answer (score 7):

Try running this first:

```
rake db:create
```

Comment: thanks gegil, as I say above, `rake db:create` gives a 'test-db already exists' message.

Answer (score 5):

I'll add the solution that helped me (should someone come across this). I had to run:

`bundle exec rake db:setup`

This re-creates a database and runs any migrations.